# ViewPager with programmatically created recyclerView lists in it

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am having some trouble with my app, I am trying to develop a list app that you have the option to add new "Goals" to as well as new lists so that you can categorize goals to a list like the list object title can be "Eat healthy" and then you'll have goals inside like "Eat more vegetables", etc. So in order to do this I have set up a ViewPagerHost class that grabs all the List objects from a SQLite database and initializes a factory developed "List fragment" that handles all the logic of adding a goal, editing and deleting, etc. I believe I've gotten this to work correctly because everything on the database side seems to work fine, and then the other classes are just supposed to display and manipulate that information. But everything on the display side seems to be going wrong. I have each view in the recyclerview display a star next to any goal marked as "important" or "life changing" but it displays the star wherever it wants. Also the list does not load until I've click on something.

```
public class ViewPagerHost extends Activity_Logger {
private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList;
private ArrayList<GoalList> goalList;
private ArrayList<Goal> goalArrayList;
Database_Controller controller;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager_host);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ad-String");
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Ambition");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    controller = Database_Controller.get(getApplicationContext());
    goalList = controller.getAllLists();
    goalArrayList = controller.getAllGoals();
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_fragments);
    if(goalList.get(0) == null){
        GoalList listOne = new GoalList();
        listOne.setTitle("DEFAULT");
        controller.insertList(listOne);
        for(int i =0; i< goalArrayList.size(); i++){
            goalArrayList.get(i).setWhich_List(listOne.getTitle());
            controller.updateGoal(goalArrayList.get(i));
        }
    }
    mFragmentList = getFragmentList(goalList);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, mFragmentList);
    if(adapter == null){

    }else{
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Fragment> getFragmentList(ArrayList<GoalList> list){
    mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
        List_Fragment list_fragment = new List_Fragment();
        bundle.putString(ARG_TITLE, goalList.get(i).getTitle());
        list_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        mFragmentList.add(list_fragment);
    }
    return mFragmentList;
}
```

}

Here is my ViewPagerHost class that creates the factory list.

```
public class List_Fragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String ARG_GOALNAME ="Goal";
private static final String ARG_IMPORTANT = "Important";
private Database_Controller mDatabaseController;
private static final String ARG_ID = "ID";
ArrayList<Goal> goalList;
LinearLayoutManager manager;
public RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
public ReceiverThread UiThread;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
String list_title;

public List_Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        list_title= bundle.getString(ARG_TITLE);
    }
    mDatabaseController = mDatabaseController.get(getContext());
    goalList = mDatabaseController.getAllListsGoals(list_title);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    UiThread = new ReceiverThread();
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    final RecyclerView_Adapter wrapperClass = new RecyclerView_Adapter(goalList,getContext(),this);
    adapter = wrapperClass.adapter;
    for(int counter =0; counter < goalList.size(); counter++){
        System.out.println(goalList.get(counter).getWhich_List());
    }
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
    //adapter goes here
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = List_Fragment.this;
            AddNew_PopUp popUp = AddNew_PopUp.newInstance(fragment);
            popUp.setTargetFragment(fragment, 0);
            popUp.show(fragmentManager, "PopUpDialog");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class ReceiverThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                goalList.clear();
                ArrayList<Goal>newGoalList = mDatabaseController.getAllGoals();
                goalList.addAll(newGoalList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode ==  0){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Goal newGoal = new Goal();
            String GoalName = data.getStringExtra(ARG_GOALNAME);
            if (GoalName.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.NoGoal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                newGoal.setmIsImportant(data.getBooleanExtra(ARG_IMPORTANT, false));
                newGoal.setmGoalName(GoalName);
                newGoal.setWhich_List(ARG_TITLE);
                mDatabaseController.insertGoal(newGoal);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String id = data.getStringExtra(ARG_ID);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),R.string.flush, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mDatabaseController.deleteGoal(id);
            }
        }else{
            if(requestCode == 2){
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    String goalName = data.getStringExtra(ARG_GOALNAME);
                    Boolean isImportant = data.getBooleanExtra(ARG_IMPORTANT, false);
                    UUID id = UUID.fromString(data.getStringExtra(ARG_ID));
                    Goal goal = mDatabaseController.getGoal(id.toString());
                    goal.setmIsImportant(isImportant);
                    goal.setmGoalName(goalName);
                    mDatabaseController.updateGoal(goal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    UiThread.run();
}

public ReceiverThread getUiThread() {
    return UiThread;
}
```

}

This is the list fragment that is created for every list in the database. It calls methods and manipulates data based off the user's actions.

```
public class RecyclerView_Adapter{
private ArrayList<Goal> mGoals;
MyAdapter adapter;
Context context;
private Database_Controller mDatabaseController;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Fragment fragment;

public RecyclerView_Adapter(ArrayList<Goal> goals, Context cntxt, Fragment fragments) {
    mGoals = goals;
    adapter = new MyAdapter(mGoals);
    context = cntxt;
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    fragment = fragments;
    mDatabaseController = Database_Controller.get(context);
}

//////////////////////////////////ADAPTER\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Goal> mGoals;


    public MyAdapter(List<Goal> goals) {
        mGoals = goals;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item_layout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Goal goal = mGoals.get(position);
        holder.bindGoal(goal);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mGoals.size();
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////ADAPTER\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\


///////////////////////////////////VIEW HOLDER\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mTextView, importantTXT;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    private Goal mGoal;
    private ImageView imgView;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity context = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                FragmentManager manager = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
                Edit_PopUp dialog = Edit_PopUp.newInstance(mGoal);
                dialog.setTargetFragment(fragment, 2);
                dialog.show(manager, "EditDialog");
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //Add delete thingy
                AppCompatActivity context = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                FragmentManager manager = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
                MoreOptions_PopUp dialog = MoreOptions_PopUp.newInstance(mGoal);
                dialog.setTargetFragment(fragment, 1);
                dialog.show(manager, "GoalDialog");
                return true;
            }
        });
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        importantTXT = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Important_textView);
        mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGoal.setFinished(mCheckBox.isChecked());
                mDatabaseController.updateGoal(mGoal);
                if (mCheckBox.isChecked() == true) {
                    boolean value = checkWinning(mGoals,context);
                    PlaySound(value, mGoal.ismIsImportant(), v);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void bindGoal(Goal goal) {
        mGoal = goal;
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mGoal.isFinished());
        mTextView.setText(mGoal.getmGoalName());
        if (mGoal.ismIsImportant()) {
            imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_stars_pressed);
            importantTXT.setText(R.string.isImportant);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkWinning(ArrayList<Goal> goals, Context context) {
        for (int i = 0; i < goals.size(); i++) {
            if (goals.get(i).isFinished() == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void PlaySound(Boolean winningSound, boolean isImportant, View view) {
        if(winningSound){
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.victory);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.completion, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }else {
            if (isImportant) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.collect);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.congrats, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.success);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.lessCongrats, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////VIEW HOLDER\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\


public MyAdapter getAdapter() {
    return adapter;
}

public Fragment getFragment() {
    return fragment;
}
```

}

Here is my adapter class that plays sounds OnClick and binds the view to the Recyclerview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the stars displayed in every row will be caused because you might be setting them when needed but not hiding them when not needed.
You will have to implement something like this in the getView() method of your adapter.

```
ImageView starView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.starView);
starView.setVisibility(goals.get(position).isSpecial() ? View.Visible : View.Gone);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working on this forever and it wasn't working.